# laravel many to may relationship

Tags: laravel, many-to-many

I have two tables passport and status and a pivot table passport_statuses.I have enter passport details and select status from dropdown but I am unable to save data in pivot table.please help.My codes are as below:

**Passport model**

```
class Passport extends Model
{
protected $fillable=[
'Full_Name',
'Date_of_Birth',
'Passport_Number',
'comments',
'Delivered_to_owner'
];
public function status()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Statuses',"passport_statuses","passport_id","statuses_id")->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

**Statuses model**

```
class Statuses extends Model
{
 protected $fillable=[
'Status_Name'
];
public function passport()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Passport',"passport_statuses","passport_id","statuses_id")->withTimestamps();
}
}
```

**PassportController**

```
public function create()
{
        $statuses=Statuses::lists('Status_Name','id');
    return view('admin.passport.create')->with('statuses',$statuses);
}
 public function store(Request $request)
{
$passport=Passport::create($request->all());
$passport->status()->attach($request->input('statuses'));
  return redirect('admin/passport');
}
```

**View**

```
{!!Form::open(['url'=>'admin/passport'])!!}
<div class="form-goup">
{!!Form::label('Full_Name','Full Name')!!}
{!!Form::text('Full_Name',null,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
</div>
<div class="form-goup">
{!!Form::label('Date_of_Birth','Date of Birth')!!}
{!! Form::input('date', 'Date_of_Birth', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Date']) !!}
</div>
{!!Form::label('Passport_Number','Passport Number')!!}
{!!Form::text('Passport_Number',null,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
<div class="form-goup">
{!!Form::label('Status_Name','Status')!!}
{!!Form::select('Status_Name',$statuses,null,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
</div>

<div class="form-group">
 {!!Form::submit('Add',['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])!!}

</div>
{!!Form::close()!!}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by changing input('statuses') to input('Status_Name') in **PassportController**

```
$passport->status()->attach($request->input('Status_Name'));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your Passport model don't `belongToMany` statuses, but `hasManyThrough` statuses.

Maybe your problem is here.

I think the line in your model `Passport.php` should be like this :

```
public function status()
{
return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Statuses',"passport_statuses","passport_id","statuses_id")->withTimestamps();
}
```

Check BelongToMany and HasMany documentation on [laravel.com](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#relationships)

Answer (score 0):

```
class Passport extends Model
{
protected $fillable=[
'Full_Name',
'Date_of_Birth',
'Passport_Number',
'comments',
'Delivered_to_owner'
];
public function status()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Statuses',"passport_statuses","passport_id","statuses_id")->withTimestamps();
    }
}


class Statuses extends Model
{
 protected $fillable=[
'Status_Name'
];
public function passport()
{
return $this->belongsToMany('App\Passport',"passport_statuses","statuses_id", "passport_id")->withTimestamps();
}
}
```

belongsToMany relation takes third argument foreign key of current Model table and 4th parameter foreighn key of related model table

of course your table has to be like this passport_statuses with with at least two columns statuses_id and passport_id.And in your example with created_at and updated_at timestamp columns